# "Inverting" datas organisation (not transpose) in R

Tags: r

Here's a sample column of my data frame, RR is a header :

```
RR
Cvv  
Cvv  
Caa
```

What I need is to "invert" the datas, so to get substrings vv and aa as headers, and RR in the data frame. The resulting matrix would be :

```
vv  | aa  
CRR |  
CRR |  
    | CRR
```

So we get the same relationships in both matrix. On the first and second row, vv is coupled with RR. On the third row, aa is coupled with RR.

Is this achievable with R ? Any ideas ?

Thanks for looking !

I oversimplified my datas in the example above. So here's a sample of my actual dataset :

```
> dput(head(A1F[4:15],n=20))
structure(list(RR = structure(c(15L, 15L, 15L, 27L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
" ", "Caa", "Caj", "Cbb", "Cbb ", "Cbv", "Cja", "Cjr", "Crj", 
"Crr", "Crv", "Cvb", "Cvr", "Cvv", "Gaa", "Gaj", "Gbb", "Gbv", 
"Gja", "Gjr", "Grj", "Grr", "Grv", "Gvb", "Gvr", "Gvv"), class = "factor"), 
    AA = structure(c(13L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 27L, 
    27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "Caa", "Caj", "Car", "Cbb", "Cbv", "Cja", "Cjr", "Cjr ", 
    "Crj", "Crr", "Crv", "Cvb", "Cvr", "Cvv", "Gaa", "Gaj", "Gbb", 
    "Gbv", "Gja", "Gjr", "Grj", "Grr", "Grv", "Gvb", "Gvr", "Gvv"
    ), class = "factor"), BB = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L
    ), .Label = c("", "?", "Caa", "Caj", "Cbv", "Cja", "Cjr", 
    "Crj", "Crr", "Crv", "Cvb", "Cvr", "Cvv", "Gaa", "Gaj", "Gbv", 
    "Gja", "Gjr", "Grj", "Grr", "Grv", "Gvb", "Gvr", "Gvv"), class = "factor"), 
    VV = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("", 
    " ", "Caa", "Caj", "Caj+", "Cbb", "Cbv", "Cja", "Cjr", "Crv", 
    "Cvb", "Cvr", "Cvv", "Gaa", "Gbb", "Gja", "Gjr", "Grv", "Gvb", 
    "Gvr"), class = "factor"), RJ = structure(c(8L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("", "Caa", "Caj", "Cbv", 
    "Ccrj", "Cja", "Cjr", "Crj", "Crj ", "Crr", "Crv", "Cvr", 
    "Cvv", "Gaa", "Gaj", "Gbv", "Gja", "Gjr", "Grj", "Grr", "Grv", 
    "Gvr", "Gvv"), class = "factor"), JR = structure(c(7L, 7L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), .Label = c("", "Caa", "Caj", 
    "Cbv", "Cja", "Cjr", "Crj", "Crr", "Crv", "Cvb", "Cvr", "Cvv", 
    "Gaa", "Gaj", "Gbv", "Gja", "Gjr", "Grj", "Grr", "Grv", "Grv ", 
    "Gvb", "Gvb ", "Gvr", "Gvv"), class = "factor"), BV = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", "Caa", "Caj", "Cbb", "Cbv", 
    "Cja", "Cjr", "Crj", "Crr", "Crv", "Cvb", "Cvr", "Cvv", "Gaa", 
    "Gaj", "Gbb", "Gbv", "Gja", "Gjr", "Grj", "Grv", "Gvb", "Gvr", 
    "Gvv", "R"), class = "factor"), VB = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
7L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 1L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Caa", "Caj", "Cbb", 
"Cbv", "Cja", "Cjr", "Crj", "Crr", "Crv", "Cvb", "Cvv", "Gaa", 
"Gaj", "Gbb", "Gbv", "Gja", "Gjr", "Grj", "Grr", "Grv", "Gvb", 
"Gvr", "Gvv"), class = "factor"), AJ = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 
1L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("", "Caa", "Caj", "Cbb", "Cbv", 
"Cja", "Cjr", "Crj", "Crv", "Cvb", "Cvr", "Cvv", "Gaa", "Gaj", 
"Gbb", "Gbv", "Gja", "Gjr", "Grj", "Grj ", "Grr", "Grv", 
"Gvb", "Gvr", "Gvv"), class = "factor"), JA = structure(c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("", "Caa", "Caj", "Cbv", 
"Cja", "Cjr", "Crr", "Crv", "Cvb", "Cvr", "Cvv", "Gaa", "Gaj", 
"Gbv", "Gja", "Gjr", "Grr", "Grv", "Gvb", "Gvv"), class = "factor"), 
VR = structure(c(1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("", 
"Caa", "Caj", "Caj ", "Cbv", "Cja", "Cjr", "Crj", "Crr", 
"Crv", "Cvb", "Cvr", "Cvv", "Gaa", "Gaj", "Gbv", "Gja", "Gjr", 
"Grj", "Grr", "Grv", "Gvb", "Gvr", "Gvv"), class = "factor"), 
RV = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Caa", "Caj", "Cbb", "Cbv", "Cja", "Cjr", "Crj", "Crr", "Crv", 
"Cvr", "Cvv", "Cvv ", "Gaa", "Gaj", "Gbb", "Gbv", "Gja", 
"Gjr", "Grj", "Grr", "Grv", "Gvr", "Gvv"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("RR", 
"AA", "BB", "VV", "RJ", "JR", "BV", "VB", "AJ", "JA", "VR", "RV"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The desired matrix would keep the relationships and row order, as stated above. GSee provided an answer that I could apply, but only to one column of my matrix, as [[ select for just specific entry and selecting multiple entry's with [ doesn't work. I'm not sure if I'm heading in the right direction with this...

Here's what the desired output (the first three rows) would look like, based on the actual dataset (as above):

```
structure(list(vv = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CRR", class = "factor"), 
    rv = c(NA, NA, NA), ja = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CVV", class = "factor"), 
    aa = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CAJ", class = "factor"), 
    bv = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "CVR"), class = "factor"), 
    aj = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "CRJ"), class = "factor"), 
    vb = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CAA", class = "factor"), 
    rj = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "CRJ"), class = "factor"), 
    rr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CBB", class = "factor"), 
    vr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CJA", class = "factor"), 
    bb = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CBV", class = "factor"), 
    jr = c(NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("vv", "rv", "ja", "aa", "bv", 
"aj", "vb", "rj", "rr", "vr", "bb", "jr"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I hope this make more sense.

Comment: Is the header always going to be two letters and are the values always "C" then two letters?

Comment: The headers are always going to be two letters but the values before the two letters will vary "C","G" or "R"

Comment: If you're going to ask a gimme teh codez question, I really don't think it is too much to ask that you provide a sample of the input data you're using (without errors), and the full output you expect from _the same_ data

Comment: @GSee Yes, I agree. I usually try to avoid, the best I can, theses questions. I also should have asked it in a better way. I thank you for taking the time to understand my query and to provide explanation with your code. It's very appreciated, I'll learn from this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. i haz teh codez 4 u.

```
#dat is the data.frame that was created from the `dput` output in the question
m <- as.matrix(dat) #convert to matrix
m[10, "AJ"] <- "" # Fix the typo/error in your data
```

Find the names of the output matrix, and make the matrix (filled with NA for now)

```
ocn <- unique(substr(paste(m[m!=""]), 2, 3)) #out column names
out <- matrix(NA, nrow(m), length(ocn))
colnames(out) <- ocn
```

loop through each row of each column

```
for (i in seq_len(NCOL(m))) { #for each column
  cn <- colnames(m)[i] #this will become the second 2 characters of new value
  for (j in seq_along(m[, i])) { # for each row of this column
    if (nzchar(m[j, i])) { # if there is something there (i.e. it is not "")
      # do the substitution
      out[j, substr(m[j, i], 2, 3)] <- paste0(substr(m[j, i], 1, 1), cn)   
    }
  }
}
out
#      vv    vb    rr    ja    rj    aj    vr    bb    jr    rv    aa    bv   
# [1,] "CRR" "CAA" "CBB" "CVV" "CJR" NA    "CJA" "CBV" NA    NA    "CAJ" NA   
# [2,] "CRR" "CAA" "CBB" "CVV" "CJR" "CRJ" "CJA" "CBV" NA    NA    "CAJ" "CVR"
# [3,] "CRR" "CAA" "CBB" "CVV" "GJR" "CRJ" "CJA" "CBV" "CVB" NA    "CAJ" "CVR"
# [4,] "GRR" NA    "CBB" "CVV" "GJR" NA    NA    "CBV" "CVB" NA    "CAJ" "CVR"
# [5,] NA    NA    "CBB" "CVV" "GJR" NA    NA    "CBV" "GVB" NA    "CAJ" "GVR"
# [6,] NA    NA    "CBB" "CVV" "GJR" NA    "CRJ" "CBV" "GVB" NA    "CAJ" "GVR"
# [7,] NA    NA    "CBB" "CVV" "GJR" NA    "CRJ" "CBV" NA    NA    "CAJ" "GVR"
# [8,] "CAA" NA    "CBB" "CVV" "GJR" NA    "CRJ" "CBV" NA    NA    "CAJ" "GVR"
# [9,] "GAA" NA    "CBB" "CVV" "GJR" "CRV" "CRJ" "CBV" NA    "CVB" NA    "GVR"
# [10,] "GAA" NA    "CBB" "CVV" "GJR" "CRV" "CRJ" "CBV" NA    "CVB" NA    "GVR"
# [11,] "GAA" NA    "CBB" "CVV" "GJR" "GRV" NA    "CBV" NA    "GVB" NA    "GVR"
# [12,] "GAA" NA    "CBB" NA    "GJR" "GRV" "CRJ" "CBV" NA    "GVB" NA    "GVR"
# [13,] "GAA" NA    "CBB" NA    "GJR" "GRV" "CRJ" "CBV" NA    "GVB" NA    "GVR"
# [14,] "GAA" NA    "CBB" "GVV" "GJR" "GRV" "CRJ" "CBV" NA    NA    NA    "GVR"
# [15,] "GAA" NA    "CBB" "GVV" "GJR" "GRV" "CRJ" "CBV" NA    "GVB" NA    "GVR"
# [16,] "GAA" NA    "CBB" "GVV" "GJR" "GRV" "CRJ" "CBV" NA    "GVB" NA    "GVR"
# [17,] "GAA" "CAJ" "CBB" "GVV" "GJR" "GRV" "CRJ" "CBV" "CJA" "GVB" NA    "GVR"
# [18,] "GAA" NA    "CBB" "GVV" "GJR" "GRV" "CRJ" "CBV" "CJA" "GVB" NA    "GVR"
# [19,] "GAA" "CAJ" "CBB" "GVV" "GJR" NA    "CRJ" "CBV" "CJA" "GVB" NA    "GVR"
# [20,] NA    "CAJ" "CBB" "GVV" "GJR" NA    "CRJ" "CBV" "CJA" NA    NA    "GVR"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation ! I managed to apply your solution to my datas and it's working fine for a single column of my matrix. I am now looking into applying this to my whole matrix. The [[ are selecting for a single value and that is causing me problems as I have 12 values in cn. Is there a simple way around this ? If not I will look ahead to post another question specifying the details.

Comment: @Chargaff If you had provided some input data with more than 1 column, I would have created a solution for that.  Instead I had to guess what another column might look like.  Also, it's not clear exactly what you want your output to look like (1 matrix or several, matrix or data.frame, using stringsAsFactors or not etc.). Hope it's useful.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not providing enough material. I edited my question and provided a sample of my actual dataset. I'm looking for one matrix or dataframe as the final output, idealy.

Comment: Then please add your desired output to your question.  It's not clear to me how you want to combine everything together into a single object.  And, which do you want -- matrix or data.frame?

Comment: Thanks for helping GSee. I provided the desired output.

Comment: @Chargaff How do you expect to end up with only 3 rows?  At the very least, don't you want a "GRR" in the "vv" column?

Comment: No, I don't expect to only have three rows, the three rows are the first three ones... Yes, GRR would go in the vv column.

Comment: "Cbb" occurs 21 times. Do you see why only the first 3 rows is not enough for me to know what you want?

Comment: So under "bb", there would be 21 "CBV". I though you understood what output I wanted as your solution did exactly what I expected (for one column). Sorry for not making myself clear enough.

Comment: Then, on what row would you put "CAJ"?

Comment: Well, CAJ is in relationship with aa bb and vb, so CAJ would go under theses, on row 1 to 8 under aa, row 10 under bb and row 17, 19 and 20 under vb. The idea is to preserve the same relationships, each row represent a time value so the relations has to stay on the same rows in the two matrix (before and after manipulations)

Comment: Row 10 of your input has 2 columns with "bb" in them.  That means that on row 10 of your output, the "bb" column should have 2 values: "CBV" and "CAJ".  It seems as though you haven't thought through what you want your output to look like.  Maybe you don't want a matrix at all; maybe you want a list.

Comment: That's an error in the datas, the bb under AJ in row 10 should not be there. I know exactly what my output should look like and you understood it as you provided me with a solution that worked for one instance.

Comment: I don't know how you came up with the order of the output columns.

Answer (score 5):

This is hard coded a bit, but the idea is there.

```
require(stringr)
require(plyr)
vect <- data.frame(RR=c("Cvv", "Cvv", "Caa"))
theMat <- t(adply(levels(vect$RR), .margins=1, .fun=function(x){str_extract(string=vect$RR, pattern=x)}))[-1 ,]
colnames(theMat) <- levels(vect$RR)
colnames(theMat) <- str_sub(colnames(theMat), start=2, end=3)
theMat <- str_replace(string=theMat, pattern=paste(colnames(theMat), collapse="|"), replacement="RR")
```

Comment: Wow, lots to learn from this answer ! I think I understand the basic idea. I'll try to apply that to my actual datas. Thank's a lot, that's a start !